# Firefox removes background when floating elements

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-float

I have a wrapper div in my css that covers most of my viewport. I have a background color and inside that div, I have two more divs floated right and left respectively.

When I'm with Chrome, I can see the background code perfectly, but when I'm with Firefox, the background color is not seen. Here are some screenshots:

**On Chrome:**
[image: My webpage on Chrome]

**On Firefox**
[image: My webpage on Firefox]

And here's the code.
*My HTML:*

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="asd"></div>
<div id="perejavi">
    <p id="pere">Pere</p>
    <p id="and">&</p>
    <p id="javi">Javi</p>
</div>
<div id="web">
    <p id="programmer">Programación</p>
    <p id="programmer2">diseño web</p>
</div>
```

*My CSS:*

```
#wrapper {
    background-color: #00CE6B;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 93%;
    width: 85%;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#perejavi {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 9.1em;
    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    height: 60%;
    width: 50%;
}

#web {
    margin: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 60%;
    float: right;
}
```

Why is this happening? Hope you can help!;)

Comment: Can you reproduce a problem at jsfiddle.net ? At first, your `<div id="wrapper">` is not closed. Second, place empty elements with `style='clear:both'` after floats to stretch the parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floats remove the HTML element from the normal document flow and can cause issues like this. There are a couple ways to handle floats but i'll just give you the way I prefer to do it:

in your css:

```
.clearfix:after {
   visibility:hidden;
    display:block;
    font-size:0;
    content:" ";
    clear:both;
    height:0;
}
```

Then in your HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper" class="clearfix>
```

This creates a pseudo element as the last child of your `.clearfix` div which [clears](http://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/) the floated elements contained within the `.clearfix` div

**note**: Also, you seem to be missing your closing `</div>` for your wrapper div. Make sure you add that in

Further reading on floats and the strangeness they bring with them:
http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Comment: Oh thanks! This worked for me, but the only problem is that in Chrome I can see the wrapper with a 100% height (from top to bottom without scrolling), but in Firefox I have less than 100% of the height. Do you know what I mean? I tried with height auto or 100% but it doesn't work at all!

Comment: Have you tried setting `html,body { height:100%; padding:0px; margin:0px }` in your css?

Comment: Hey! Sorry I wasn't able to reply... I did this but it keeps doing a scroll... What else can I do?

Comment: If you can create a jsfiddle showing the problem I can try to help you solve it

Comment: Sorry for being late! I'll already solved this... It was a height problem! I didn't see I had an auto value for height, so I put a value and now it can be seen perfectly! Thanks!